# Does lock escalation to table level depend upon the number of columns in a table in mssqlserver?

Tags: sql-server, locking

If I have a table with 100000 rows and I am deleting 60000 rows based on some indexed columns (so that there is an index seek)  in a transaction, is it always necessary that the optimizer will escalate the locking level to Table as per the condition of holding more than 5000 locks in mssqlserver ? Would the escalation also depend upon the size of the row (by that I mean number of columns in a table) ?

Comment: The speed of escalation could depend on row width, since wider rows take more pages to store.   If this is an issue for you, you could do the DELETE with a tablelock, set isolation level to serializable, and get the locks set from the start.  or you could do the deletes in batches to stay below the table lock threshold

Comment: @uesr1443098 - I didn't catch the isolation level part, why serializable ? deleting in batches is a good option but the number in a batch has to be very carefully chosen keeping in mind the concurrency and also if there is no concurrency the operation shouldn't be slow. Also is it possible that even if the index seek is happening and the lock escalation has not happened, the transaction takes a lock on a row which does not come in the output of seek operation.

Comment: Serializable ensure you get full access at the outset and will not wait on others once you start deleting.  It's the nuclear option.  how's it coming with doing  your deletes in batches?  And, no, there should be no row locks on uninvolved rows, though if there is a page lock, it would amount to the same thing.

Comment: @user1443098- works for me, thanks.